# Is there any better way of doing this? - android text color change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to highlight names in a edittext,
So I have a String array with those words.
I have created this following code that highlights the word written in the edittext if it is found in the words Array:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        String allText = mac.getText().toString();
        for(int i=0;i<allText.length();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<darkBlue.length;j++){
                if(allText.indexOf(darkBlue[j])!=-1){
                    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(allText);        
                    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), allText.indexOf(darkBlue[j]), allText.indexOf(darkBlue[j])+darkBlue[j].length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    mac.setText(WordtoSpan);
                    mac.setSelection(mac.getText().length());//put the cursor at the end of the text.
                }
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

The problem is, that every second the UI renders again, thus not letting me interact with the keyboard, and it's all behaving slowly.
Do you know any better alternative, for highlighting several words in a textedit in android from an array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

Only post the setText and setselection to the ui thread. Everything that doesn't directly interact with a ui element should be done on another thread

Answer (score 0):

Well your algorithm could certainly be optimized - see my example later on in the post.  But more importantly, as the other poster said, better to offload the work to another thread and then only post the important stuff.  A common misonception is that, by posting in a handler, you're running in a different thread, which is not the case. do your processing in another thread and post back only the part that manipulates the UI: (some algorithm changes included, let me know if Its not clear or i totally screwed up :) )

```
private void startWork() {
  new Thread(doWork).start();
}

Runnable doWork = new Runnable() {
  while (true) { // alter this condition to meet your needs
    for(int j=0;j<darkBlue.length;j++){
      String subText = mac.getText().toString();
      int length = darkBlue[j].length();
      int sub = subText.indexOf(darkBlue[j]);
      int index = 0;
      while(sub > 0){)
       index += (sub + length);
       colorSpan(Color.Blue, (index - length), index);
       allText = allText.substring(sub + length);
       sub = subText.indexOf(darkBlue[j]);
      }
    }
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}

private void colorSpan(Color color, final int start, final int stop) {
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      String allText = mac.getText().toString();
      Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(allText);        
      WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, stop, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      mac.setText(WordtoSpan);
      mac.setSelection(mac.getText().length());
    }
  });
}
```

NOTE: I did this in a bit of a hurry, pardon me if there are any glaring mistakes